# MAUI Blazor - Application deployment error

Tags: c#, android, graphql, blazor, maui

When I publish the application for Android, I get this error:
"Failed to create app. The "GraphQLDefRule" rule is missing the "{ItemType}" property."

I don't know if this helps, but I'm using ChilliCream and Telerik components.

Do you have any idea where my problem might be coming from?

Comment: Given the context I'd guess it's coming from the ChilliCream packages.
You'll probably need to provide more detail to get a detailed answer though.

Answer (score 0):

The official document said:

> During development, .NET Android uses a debug keystore to sign the app, which allows it to be deployed directly to an emulator or to devices configured to run debuggable apps. However, this keystore isn't recognized as a valid keystore for the purposes of distributing apps. Therefore, a private keystore must be created and used for signing release builds

So you can try to [Create a keystore file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-7.0%22https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fmaui%2Fandroid%2Fdeployment%2Fpublish-cli%3Fview%3Dnet-maui-7.0%22#create-a-keystore-file) and [Publish the Android app using the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-7.0%22https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fmaui%2Fandroid%2Fdeployment%2Fpublish-cli%3Fview%3Dnet-maui-7.0%22). This will resolve the problem.